# Style elements inside a Host element

Tags: css, sass

I have the following host element with class:

```
<my-component class="show-ghost">
  <div>some content</div>
</my-component>
```

I can successfully style this `Host` element from within the `my-component`:

```
:host(.show-ghost) {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

However, I want to style all child / nested elements ("some content" div) of this host element. I tried this:

```
:host(.show-ghost) {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  
  // below doesn't work
  & > * {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work for me.